# multiple instances of different objects

Tags: opengl

Im trying to make 3D chess.

Just now Ive found out about `glDrawArraysInstanced()` which allows me to draw one of my objects multiple times (ie pawns). But Ive run into another problem.

I dont really know how I would go about drawing 2 objects with a single `glDrawArraysInstanced()` call (I presume it shouldnt be done this way).

From the top of my head I can think of possibly having multiple `glDrawArraysInstanced()` calls for each individual piece (which would be 6 + 1 for board) but I heard that having multiple draw calls is bad.

Searching the https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki I stumbled upon `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect()` and other similiar drawing calls but Im not entirely sure if this could help.

Anyhow I will be grateful for all answers you can give.

TL;DR dont know how to `glDrawArraysInstanced()` with multiple different objects in one call.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Purely for future knowledge would `glMultiDrawArraysIndirect()` be the correct answer if I had 2323727212 models to draw?

Comment: "*I heard that having multiple draw calls is bad*" In what context? In a context where you're drawing hundreds of thousands of things, maybe. In a context where you're drawing a *chess board*? No.